# a quartic and a tangent

Tags: polynomials, tangent-line

If $P(x)$ is a quartic polynomial and if $l$ is the line that is tangent to the graph $P(x)$ at two places and $l(x)$ is the function defined by line $l$, how do I know for sure that $P(x)-l(x)$ is then tangent to the x-axis at two points?

The original problem is as follows - if it helps you understand my question better: Show that if $P(x)$ is a quartic polynomial then there exists at most one line $\ell$ that is tangent to the graph of $P(x)$ at two places.

Comment: if $P(a) = l(a)$, then $P(a) - l(a) = 0$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: A line "tangent to the x-axis" **is** the x-axis!

Comment: but since P(x) is a quartic and l(x) is linear, that can't be true, can it...?

Comment: @ John Lou I don't think so. Not really

Comment: Let $Q(x) = P(x) - l(x)$, if $P(x)$ is tangent to $l$ at two points $a,b$, then $P(a) = l(a), P'(a) = l'(a), P(b) = l(b), P'(b) = l'(b)$. This implies $Q(a) = Q'(a) = Q(b) = Q'(b) = 0$. So $Q(x)$ is tangent to $x$-axis at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish that had been more obvious to me before...

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x) = a_4 x^4 + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 $

Take a point $(x, P(x))$ on the graph of $P(x)$ and create the tangent line at that point.  The slope of this line is $P'(x)$; if $x + t$, where $ t \ne 0$ is another point on the graph where the slope is $P'(x)$ then

$ P'(x) = \dfrac{ P(x+t) - P(x) }{t} $

i.e.

$P(x+t) - P(x) = t P'(x) $

Substitute the various quantities, you get,

$a_4 ((x+t)^4 - x^4) + a_3 ((x+t)^3 - x^3) + a_2 ((x+t)^2 - x^2) + a_1 t = t ( 4 a_4 x^3 + 3 a_3 x^2 + 2 a_2 x + a_1) $

This reduces to,

$ a_4 ( 6 x^2 t^2 + 4 x t^3 + t^4) + a_3 ( 3 x t^2 + t^3 ) + a_2 ( t^2 ) = 0$

Dividing by $t^2$

$ a_4 (6 x^2 + 4 x t + t^2) + a_3 (3 x + t ) + a_2 = 0 \tag{1} $

We also have

$P'(x) = P'(x+t) $

So

$ 4 a_4 x^3 + 3 a_3 x^2 + 2 a_2 x + a_1 = 4 a_4 (x+t)^3 + 3 a_3 (x + t)^2 + 2 a_2 (x + t) + a_1 $

Therefore,

$ 4 a_4 ( 3 x^2 t + 3 x t^2 + t^3) + 3 a_3 (2 x t + t^2) +2 a_2 t = 0 $

Dividing by $t$

$ 4 a_4 ( 3 x^2 + 3 x t + t^2) + 3 a_3 (2 x + t) + 2 a_2 = 0 \tag{2} $

Now substitute for $a_2$ from $(1)$ into $(2)$:

$4 a_4 ( 3 x^2 + 3 x t + t^2) + 3 a_3 (2 x + t) - 2 \bigg(a_4 (6 x^2 + 4 x t + t^2) + a_3 (3 x + t )\bigg) = 0 $

This gives,

$ 4 a_4 x t + 2 a_4 t^2 + a_3 t = 0 \tag{3} $

Divide by $t$:

$ 4 a_4 x + 2 a_4 t + a_3 = 0 $

$ x = - \dfrac{ 2 a_4 t + a_3 } {4 a_4} = - \dfrac{1}{2} t - \dfrac{a_3}{4 a_4}$

Let $ k = \dfrac{a_3}{4 a_4} $, then

$ x = -\dfrac{1}{2} t - k \tag{4}$

Substitute for $x$ into $(1)$

$a_4 (6 ( -\dfrac{1}{2} t - k )^2  + 4 t (-\dfrac{1}{2} t - k) + t^2) + a_3 (3 \cdot ( - \dfrac{1}{2} t - k ) + t ) + a_2 = 0$

This reduces to

$ a_4 ( \dfrac{1}{2} t^2 + 2 t k + 6 k^2 ) + a_3 ( -\dfrac{1}{2} t - 3 k ) + a_2 = 0 $

The coefficient of $t$ is

$ 2 a_4 k - \dfrac{1}{2} a_3 $

But $ k = \dfrac{a_3}{4a_4} $ , therefore the coefficient is zero.

Therefore, we now have,

$ a_4 ( \dfrac{1}{2} t^2 + 6 k^2 ) + a_3 (- 3 k ) + a_2 = 0 $

which is of the form

$ A t^2 + B = 0 $

Since $t$ cannot be zero, then if this equation has solutions, they will be only two solutions which are negatives of each other.

i.e

$ t_2 = - t_1 $

Recall equation $(4)$ which says that

$ x = -\dfrac{1}{2} t - k $

Therefore, if

$ x_1 = -\dfrac{1}{2} t_1 - k $

and

$ x_2 = - \dfrac{1}{2} t_2 - k $

Then we have to show that

$x_2 = x_1 + t_1 \tag{*} $

To show this, we have from the above two equations,

$ x_2 - x_1 = - \dfrac{1}{2} (t_2 - t_1) = t_1 $

Thus $(*)$ holds true.

Equation $(*)$ Says that the second solution is just the first but mirrored.

Therefore, the two solutions will give the same line.  And hence we've proven that there will at most be one line tangent to a quartic polynomial graph.